# Coding an update, do I change the provisioning profile back?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have just released my first app. I want to start working on improving it and updating. Before I submitted my project and used the production provisioning profile I made a copy of the project so I would retain one with the development provisioning profile.

How do I go about updating? Can I use my old version and just increment the version number and install a production certificate on it and submit? Or should I use the version I just submitted and change the certificate back to development? Or does it not matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just keep developing with the version you used last. The provisioning profiles do not matter because in *Build Settings* there should be some defined for release (release / production profiles) and the others for development. 
Even though, it is a good habit to have a recovery version of the last AppStore version of your app somewhere zipped, simply as backup if you're not using version / source control.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: cool thanks for that, is it okay to use the old version too and then add the production profile?

Comment: Yes sure, if you have all of the provisioning profiles and certificates, then that should not be a problem.